# How can we open iPhone/android native keyboard using phonegap or javascript

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova

In my Phonegap application i need one div which is scrollable, When user click on it device keyboard should be open and text should be writeable in div. But i dont know how to open device native keyboard for both device. Is there any plugin available for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have a hidden input field, and `onclick` event of that div, simply call `focus()` for that input field. It'll automatically bring up the keyboard. And then you can read the content of the input field and write that into the div.

Comment: yes good logic i will try this and it will be scrollable or not?